# Add letters control to input

Tags: jquery, html

Part of my html inputs :

```
    <form class="form" id="firstForm" novalidate="novalidate">  
       <div class="tab-content">
           <div class="tab-pane active" id="vtab1">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo _("Hasta Adı"); ?></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                     <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control">
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo _("Hasta Soyadı"); ?></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                     <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control">
                  </div>
              </div>
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo _("Hasta Yaşı"); ?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" required><label for="age" class="error"></label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    // With Form Validation Wizard
    var $validator = jQuery("#firstForm").validate({
    highlight: function(element) {
      jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    success: function(element) {
      jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
    });

    jQuery('#validationWizard').bootstrapWizard({
        tabClass: 'nav nav-pills nav-justified nav-disabled-click',
        onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
          return false;
        },
        onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
          var $valid = jQuery('#firstForm').valid();
          if(!$valid) {

            $validator.focusInvalid();
            return false;
          }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to add letter control to only firstname and lastname. I don' t want to add a rule for all form. How can i add some rules for specific inputs using `jquery.validate.min.js` library on bootstrapwizard' s next event ?

Comment: within `validate` declare it as `rules` option and provide your respective `input`  element `name/id`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thank you, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `rules` option in `jquery-validate plugin`. Consider below example.

```
var $validator = jQuery("#firstForm").validate({
    rules:{
        firstName:{
             required:true
             //any other similar rules
        },
        lastName:{
             required:true,
             //any other similar rules
        }
    },
    messages:{
        firstName:{
             required:"FirstName is required"
             //any other similar rule messages
        },
        lastName:{
             required:"LastName is required",
             //any other similar messages
        }
    }
    highlight: function(element) {
      jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    success: function(element) {
      jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

To dynamically add rules, you can do it as below:

```
$("input[name=firstName]").rules("add", "yourcustomrule");
```

> But remember, before you write above line you need to initialize
>   `form` with `validate`